# C++ call class constructor from another class

Tags: c++

I currently have a problem when I want to declare a class in another class. The following is my code. When I call the class `Shape` in the `main` function, there is no error. It turns out to be problematic if I want to define a `Shape` (**myshape1**) in `Rectangle`, it pops up the error:

```
class_constructor_derived.C:22:18: error: ‘a’ is not a type
   Shape myshape1(a,b);
```

any suggestions will be thankful!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
using namespace std;

class Shape 
{
public:
  Shape(int h,int w){
    height = h;
    width = w;
    printf("creatig shape\n");
  } 
  int width;
  int height;
};

class Rectangle
{
  public:
  int a = 5;
  int b = 6;
  Shape myshape1(a,b); //something wrong here
  
};

int main(void)
{
   Rectangle Rect;
   cout<<Rect.myshape1.width<<endl;

   //the following works good
   int c = 7;
   int d = 8;
   Shape myshape2(c, d);
   cout<<myshape2.width<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Shape myshape1(a,b); //something wrong here" I don't understand what you want this line of code to do. You said something about "calling the constructor", but for what purpose? Do you want `Rectangle` to be a subclass of `Shape`? Do you want the `Rectangle` class to have a member that is a `Shape`? Something else?

Comment: Did you mean to inherit `Rectangle` from `Shape`? That actual code is complete nonsense with all respect. You should go back to your textbook and recur the relevant sections about class inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: Change it to `Shape myshape1 = Shape(a, b);`, the constructor needs to be called, not the () operador.

Comment: @Alex, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this code:

```
Shape myshape1(a,b); //something wrong here
```

...looks to the compiler like a function declaration. Except that when it looks up the meaning of `a` and `b`, it find that neither one is a type, which is what it would need to be for the function declaration to be valid.

The easy fix (assuming a reasonably current compiler) is to use curly braces instead of parentheses:

```
Shape myshape1{a,b}; //nothing wrong here
```

Depending on the compiler you're using, you may have to enable the current version of the language to allow this (it wasn't supported in C++98). With g++ or clang, you'd use a flag something like `-std=c++14` or `std=c++17` (but note: curly-brace initialization was added at the same time as in-place initialization of struct/class members, so this was also required for the original to work as I presume it was intended to).

Disclaimer: depending on what you're trying to accomplish, there may be other things in the code you want to change. For one obvious example, a `Shape` vs. `Rectangle` relationship is one that you might well want to model with inheritance. This is actually a fairly unusual situation: people tend to use inheritance where it doesn't make sense, but in this case you haven't used it, even though this is one of the rare cases where it actually might might make sense.